# Microsoft Lync video streaming to webbrowser

Tags: stream, video-streaming, lync, lync-server-2010

is it possible to stream (previously recorded and/or live) video to many Microsoft Lync SDK webbrowser clients?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Comment: What do you mean by lync SDK webbrowser client? What exactly are you running on the client?

Comment: I need to create a client, that runs in a webbrowser (Silverlight) and plays video.

Comment: Will Lync be installed on the client machine?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is No - not without some pain. The long answer depends on your exact scenario.

If you can control the client build, and are able to ensure Lync is installed, then you should be able to automate Lync from the Silverlight app to connect to the conference that is hosting the video content you want to display. With this solution, it will be Lync that's actually displaying the video, not Silverlight. That's pretty simple, and covered in the [Lync SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436915.aspx).

Otherwise, you'll have some work to do. I'd imagine that you could put together a solution using [UCMA 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg421023.aspx) to build a Lync application to control a conference and get access to the video stream, then stream that to the Silverlight clients using [IIS Live Smooth Streaming](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/620/getting-started-with-iis-live-smooth-streaming/) or something similar. This wouldn't be real time video, so there would be a slight delay, but if your video is one way only (e.g. lectures being consumed by students), then that shouldn't be a problem.

It's worth bearing in mind that this is not a solved problem yet (at least, within MS) as even the [Lync Web App](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/welcome-to-microsoft-lync-web-app-HA101908015.aspx) (the official Silverlight Lync Client) does not support video.

Comment: What do you mean by "control the client build"?

Comment: Basically, can you guarantee that Lync will be installed on the client?

Comment: OK, so you can have one machine start a conference and play the content you want to share. Then on the machines consuming the content, you can use the Lync SDK from Silverlight to get Lync to join to that conference. Bear in mind that you won't be able to get the video stream directly into Silverlight - Lync itself will show the video window. This link shows you how to join to a conference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436915.aspx